# YouTube IFrame API for Android, settings layout with long names doesn't fit

Tags: android, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to integrate the YpuTube IFrame player into my webview-based application. The player itself is included, but if you open the settings section and select subtitles with a long title, they are cut off.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85aAT.png)

I think the problem is related to the YouTube branch, that it does not know how to shorten names in such cases.
Are there any other options for how this panel can be displayed?